# set-wise combinations in Python3

Tags: numpy, python-3.6

I have four sets (a-d in this example) and I'd like to iterate through all combinations with the restriction that you can only pick one element from each set and you need to pick one from all sets. In the case of four sets you could simply do something like this:

```
for a in (1,2):
    for b in (3,4):
        for c in (5,6):
            for d in (7,8):
                print(a,b,c,d)
```

And the expected output would be:

```
1 3 5 7
1 3 5 8
1 3 6 7
1 3 6 8
1 4 5 7
1 4 5 8
1 4 6 7
1 4 6 8
2 3 5 7
2 3 5 8
2 3 6 7
2 3 6 8
2 4 5 7
2 4 5 8
2 4 6 7
2 4 6 8
```

**How could I rewrite this for n-sets?**

I'm hoping for something like `itertools.combinations()`. Or iterating over a n-dimensional array. Probably nympy have something?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that `itertools.product`?

Comment: That's exactly what it is! Thanks! Please provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `numpy` solution:

```
a = tuple(np.arange(x,x+2) for x in range(0,8,2))
a
# (array([0, 1]), array([2, 3]), array([4, 5]), array([6, 7]))
for x,y,z,u in np.broadcast(*np.ix_(*a)):
    print(x,y,z,u) 
# 0 2 4 6
# 0 2 4 7
# 0 2 5 6
# 0 2 5 7
# 0 3 4 6
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Paul Panzer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7207392/paul-panzer) suggested in a comment. This is [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and the example would look like this:

```
import itertools
for p in itertools.product((1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8)):
    print(p)

(1, 3, 5, 7)
(1, 3, 5, 8)
(1, 3, 6, 7)
(1, 3, 6, 8)
(1, 4, 5, 7)
(1, 4, 5, 8)
(1, 4, 6, 7)
(1, 4, 6, 8)
(2, 3, 5, 7)
(2, 3, 5, 8)
(2, 3, 6, 7)
(2, 3, 6, 8)
(2, 4, 5, 7)
(2, 4, 5, 8)
(2, 4, 6, 7)
(2, 4, 6, 8)
```